# err: truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to implement a maxnet NN, and I got that error while I was trying to define my activation function, how can I get rid of this error?

```
     import numpy as np

    def AF (Self):
       if x>0:
     return x
   return 0



     x= np.array([1.2, 1.1, 0.9, 0.95, 1])
     eps= 0.15
     y=np.zeros(5)
     count=0
     temp=sum(x)

   while True:
      for i in range (5):
      val= x[i]- eps*temp +eps*x[i]
      y= np.append(AF(val))
      x= y.copy()
      count+=1
      if sum(y)== max(y):
         break


   print(y)
```

Comment: Could you try fixing the indentation of your code?

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown when you try to use an array as a boolean. In your `AF` function you are getting an array instead of a single number, so it does not know if it should evaluate to `True` or `False` when doing `if x>0:`.

In your code this happens because you are using `x` instead of the passed parameter, try redefining your function like:

```
def AF(val):
  if val > 0:
      return val
  return 0
```

Comment: thank you. that error is gone after correcting this way but got another error: TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values' that can not catch it!

Comment: @rezvanehzahedi If you could post your code with good indentation I could help more, but like that it makes no sense.

Comment: can not understand what you mean by good identation, what do you mean by it?

Comment: Indentation are the spaces for each line. In Python indentation is important. The code you posted in the question has wrong indentation, it makes no sense.

Comment: But well, you are using np.append, check out the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html), you need to give the array and the elements to be inserted, you are passing only one argument.